# PHP coding in HTML to create front end of a website

Tags: php, mysql

How exactly does PHP code in HTML document help navigate to a different web page by clicking on a link? Please help. I'd like to have a simple example of PHP code. I am using CMS as back end
(PHP/MySQL). Please help me in creating front end in PHP for a website.

Comment: You are not very clear in your question. Can you provide a diagram or elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it all wrong, or maybe you didn't express yourself correctly. Are you pertaining to the pagination?

The best thing I can suggest is, read an open source CMS [source code](http://code.google.com/p/madebyfrogs/downloads/list) or a [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/php-for-beginners-building-your-first-simple-cms/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/other_page.html' ) ; ?>
```

is that what you want? thats the php code to navigate to a different page,you can put this in your html page

Comment: Teaching this without `exit;` is a bad idea.